# In R, is there a way of seeing how many times an element in one column corresponds to specific element in another one?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table that shows patient visits to a hospital. One can see which doctor they see each time, like this:

```
Patient <- c("pat_1", " pat_2", " pat_3", " pat_4", " pat_5", " pat_1", " pat_2", " pat_3", " pat_4", " pat_5", " pat_1", " pat_2", " pat_3", " pat_4", " pat_5")
Year <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002)
Doctor <- c("A", " A", " B", " B", " C", " A", " A", " B", " C", " C", " A", " B", " C", " B", " C")
Doc.per.pat <- data.frame(Patient, Year, Doctor)
```

The table has about 150 thousand rows, where each patient might appear several times (often more than once each year). I would like to get an outcome over the number of times each patient sees each doctor, like in the following table:

```
Doc.per.patient.outcome <- matrix(c(3,0,0 ,2,1,0 ,0,2,1 ,0,2,1 ,0,0,3), ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
rownames(Doc.per.patient.outcome) <- gl(5, 1, labels = c(paste("pat", 1:5, sep = "_")))
colnames(Doc.per.patient.outcome) <- c("A", "B", "C")
Doc.per.patient.outcome <- as.table(Doc.per.patient.outcome)
Doc.per.patient.outcome
```

I'm totally stuck. Have been thinking about dplyr and "select" into patient and year. Then "count" or "table" for each patient. Then I would have the doctors each patient has met. But the problem is how that could be transformed into a table, or data frame.

Comment: Not sure I understand 100%, but does `as.data.frame(table(Patient = Doc.per.pat$Patient, Doctor = Doc.per.pat$Doctor))` do the trick?

Comment: `Doc.per.pat %>% group_by(Patient, Doctor) %>% summarise(n =n()) %>% spread(key = Doctor, value = "n")` would also do it, in this case you can use more columns to calculate the statistics on (for example patient by doctor by year) as well as just add it to the raw data if you want.

Comment: Is this `library(data.table); setDT(Doc.per.pat)[, .N, by = .(Patient, Doctor)]` what you're trying to obtain?

Comment: you can use better title for your question and explain your question in the post, not in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the OP makes references aggregating the data by year but the desired output aggregates across years, we will first aggregate the data including a `Year` column, and then build the a cross-year table from the year level summary.

To obtain a data frame that has the counts of doctor visits by patient, year, and doctor, one can use `dplyr::summarise()`. Note that I edited the data so patient `pat_1` visits doctor `A` twice in the year 2000 so the summarized table looks different than the original data.

```
Patient <- c("pat_1", "pat_1", "pat_3", "pat_4", "pat_5", "pat_1", "pat_2", "pat_3", "pat_4", "pat_5", "pat_1", "pat_2", "pat_3", "pat_4", "pat_5")
Year <- c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002)
Doctor <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C")
Doc.per.pat <- data.frame(Patient, Year, Doctor)
library(dplyr)
Doc.per.pat %>% group_by(Patient,Year,Doctor) %>% summarise(n = n()) ->aggData
aggData
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   Patient, Year [14]
   Patient  Year Doctor     n
   <fct>   <dbl> <fct>  <int>
 1 pat_1    2000 A          2
 2 pat_1    2001 A          1
 3 pat_1    2002 A          1
 4 pat_2    2001 A          1
 5 pat_2    2002 B          1
 6 pat_3    2000 B          1
 7 pat_3    2001 B          1
 8 pat_3    2002 C          1
 9 pat_4    2000 B          1
10 pat_4    2001 C          1
11 pat_4    2002 B          1
12 pat_5    2000 C          1
13 pat_5    2001 C          1
14 pat_5    2002 C          1
>
```

At this point the data is in what is called [narrow form tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), where one row represents the count of visits for a unique combination of patient, year, and doctor.

A solution in Base R to aggregate including `Year` uses the `stats::aggregate()` function. First, we create a `Count` vector that we include in the input data frame that is summed in `aggregate()`.

```
Count <- rep(1,length(Doctor))
Doc.per.pat <- data.frame(Patient, Year, Doctor,Count)
aggData <- aggregate(Count ~ Patient + Year + Doctor, data = Doc.per.pat,FUN="sum")
```

The output matches the results from `dplyr::summarise()`, so we won't duplicate it here.

The data can be further aggregated using `xtabs()` or by eliminating the `Year` column from `summarise()`. The `xtabs()` version is:

```
xtabs(n ~ Patient + Doctor,aggData)
```

...and the output is:

```
> xtabs(n ~ Patient + Doctor,aggData)
       Doctor
Patient A B C
  pat_1 4 0 0
  pat_2 1 1 0
  pat_3 0 2 1
  pat_4 0 2 1
  pat_5 0 0 3
>
```

One can generate an output suitable for printing by extending the solution with `knitr::kable()` as follows.

```
library(knitr)
kable(xtabs(n ~ Patient + Doctor,aggData))
```

...and the output:

```
|      |  A|  B|  C|
|:-----|--:|--:|--:|
|pat_1 |  4|  0|  0|
|pat_2 |  1|  1|  0|
|pat_3 |  0|  2|  1|
|pat_4 |  0|  2|  1|
|pat_5 |  0|  0|  3|
>
```

When viewed in an HTML browser or editor that reads markdown, the table looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, almost like the one proposed two hours ago :).

Comment: The one proposed 2 hours ago didn't account for the year variable :(.

Comment: Sure, what you want ;) although it is mentioned and not in the given output.

Comment: The simplest answer is the one using Base R to aggregate across years. When I noticed that someone had downvoted this answer, I inferred that year was required and posted an answer.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JoimHauks - you're welcome. If the answer does answer your question, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
as.data.frame(table(Patient = Doc.per.pat$Patient, Doctor = Doc.per.pat$Doctor))
```